# sb-admin + datatables.js : Duplicate "sorting" row when "sScroolX" and "sScrollXInner" are configured

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

- I am using **sb-admin** with **datatables.js**.
- I want my data table scrollable horizontally
- So I add two features "sScrollX" and "sScrollXInner". And it works.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
          responsive: true,
          sScrollX: "100%",
          sScrollXInner: "120%",
      });
  });
  ```
- But now the table looks like this:
  [image]
- The second row is redundant and there are two groups of sorting
  icons.
- Could you please tell me how to remove the second row? Thanks.